# json passing to D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to load data into a D3 script but have difficulties getting the data prosessed in the Dendogranm example. The data comes from the server as follows:

```
d3.json( [{"name": "flare", "children": [{"name": "analytics", "children": [{"name": "cluster", "children": [{"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938}, {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812}, {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714}, etc
```

The following error occurs in the cluster creation: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'depth' of undefined"

```
var nodes = cluster.nodes(root),
    links = cluster.links(nodes);
```

So d3.json is not the proper construct. I assume this must be changed to

```
var flare = [{"name": "flare", "children": [{"name": "analyti ...

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

var nodes = cluster.nodes( flare ),
  links = cluster.links(nodes);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(links)
.enter().append("path")
```

Kinds regards supporting me.

Comment: Uh? d3.json takes a URL as argument not a javascript array. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same error, it was because I was trying to define a pack layout without setting the width and height properly.

If your `cluster` variable was defined like:

```
var cluster = d3.layout.pack()
  .size([width, height])
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  });
```

That should work for you.  `d.values` would refer to a size (number)

I believe that `flare` also needs to be an object instead of an array.